# Incoming voice is not getting recorded in Android

Tags: android, call-recording

I have gone through all the links in Stack overflow related this call recording issue with incoming voice. My app is able to record the **outgoing voice** clearly but not the **incoming voice**. I know, Google has withdrawn this service from Android 7.0. Is there any way so that we can record the calls with the both voices? Please help me if you have anything with this.

Here are few links from the Stack overflow that I have followed

[Android Call Recording Incoming voice not getting recorded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231232/android-call-recording-incoming-voice-not-getting-recorded)

[cannot hear incoming voice in recorded calls in android 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435539/cannot-hear-incoming-voice-in-recorded-calls-in-android-7)

[Android Call Recording Incoming voice not getting recorded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231232/android-call-recording-incoming-voice-not-getting-recorded)

[Incoming voice not getting recorded in Samsung S7, S8 and Gionee A1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47751462/incoming-voice-not-getting-recorded-in-samsung-s7-s8-and-gionee-a1)

[Android can't record incoming calls with clear voice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877597/android-cant-record-incoming-calls-with-clear-voice)

As per my knowledge what I got from the links shared above is that to record incoming voice it needs the `CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT` permission. This permission is now allowed for the system apps only. So, what else? Please share some solution on this to overcome this common issue.

Comment: I also want answer for this question!

Comment: [Android can't record incoming calls with clear voice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877597/android-cant-record-incoming-calls-with-clear-voice)   Is my question

Comment: Please Add Your Code Here...

Comment: Hi Usman, I have followed this link for the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887636/how-to-record-phone-calls-in-android
Please follow the answer given by Vulovic Vukasin.